# Transform results of a Netmeta object

Tags: r, math, transformation

I am conducting a network MA using the netmeta package and, since i don't have directly the RR of all the studies included, I used the `escalc` function form metafor to calculate logRR and relative se in order to use them as objects for the `TE` and `seTE`required by netmeta.

However, doing so i have now the logRR and relative CI. I'd like to obtain the actual RR and CI but i don't know hot to exponentiate them.

I would really apreciate any form of help.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

I found a solution by myself, hope to be helpful to someone else in the future:

I used the `netmetabin` function form netmeta giving them directly the arm-level data of my studies. By setting the `sm=RR` and `method="Inverse"`it will then give you the results as RR(CI) rather than logRR(CI).

Enjoy!